# Link for sharing on fb and/or twitter

Tags: facebook, twitter, sharing, facebook-social-plugins

What is the easiest way to reward user with a link to a pdf for sharing content on facebook or twitter? It doesn't need to be super secure, but would be nice if user really posted something before showing him a link.
Best,

Michał

Comment: You are __not allowed__ to reward users for sharing on Facebook. Go read their [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) please. (Point 4.5 is applicable here.)

Comment: How about twitter? Is it allowed to reward users with a pdf for tweeting something?